# Multi-Facet Interactions

Tags: marklogic, faceted-search, marklogic-8

I want to implement multi-facet interaction by MarkLogic `search:search` API. In MarkLogic `jsearch.facets` there is one option 'othersWhere' which may help to build the same. However, I want to implement it by search:search.

Could I achieve this by creating custom facets with `search:search` API?

For example, I have one element `<color>` which has values *green*, *red*, *blue* and *white*. In normal scenario, whenever user will click on `color:green` it will hide the other options, but I want to select multiple values from the same constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely specify more than one value for a constraint to apply with search:search. For example a search string like:

```
color:"Red" OR color:"Green"
```

..Will return all documents with a color of red or a color of green using the "color" constraint.

To me this sounds mostly like a UI building challenge.

Comment: Yes, I know we can specify more than one value in constraint. However, I am looking for backend solution which is given in jsearch.facets only

Comment: @NavinRawat It's really not clear to me what you're looking to do. As I demonstrated, it's possible to return documents that have at least one value of a set of possible values assigned to a constraint. You wrote "I want to select multiple values from the same constraint." which this solution accomplishes. Could you elaborate what you're seeking to do?

Comment: In normal scenario whenever user click something (color:green) it refreshes the whole facets. So, user will get color:green as selected facet only, he will not get any other options to select (color:red etc). So, the question is if system is returning only one facet how user can select multiple. By jsearch:facet we can achieve this. Do we have anything in search:search which can help us to achieve the same.

Comment: @NavinRawat As my answer explains, you can do this with search:search by leveraging the grammar of the search string (first parameter) of search:search. The brunt of this work will be handled by your UI constructing the correct search string.

Comment: It seems you are not getting what is othersWhere.

Answer (score 0):

That will be difficult I'm afraid. You can take `search:search` apart, and do `search:parse` and `search:resolve` separately, giving you somewhat more flexibility, but that still doesn't really help with doing what you are trying to do. For this, you'd need to resolve each facet separately, and pass in a tweaked query each time, essentially omitting the query part for the facet itself each time. That is rather cumbersome, and MarkLogic would be unable to optimize subsequent facet calculations.

As an alternative, why don't you hold on to the facet while a user is still clicking, and only submit when the user has selected all values for the facet? I've done this in the past. The user would toggle to a multi-select mode for a facet, and in that case, the user could checkbox as many values as desired, and would finish off with a button-click to apply.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks Grtjn, yes we can achieve this by forcing user to submit request after selecting the facets. But, in our scenario we have to refresh facets, and result on each selection/click. Search:search is very old API compared to jsearch.facets. However, this whereof functionality is missing in search:search.